# Concatenating string and variable in xslt

Tags: variables, xslt, concatenation

I would like to parametrise a DB-ConnectionString.
How can I concat this `DBSchema` variable to the rest of the cs string?

```
<xsl:variable name="DBSchema" select="'sa'" />
```

I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="ConnectionString" select="concat('Data Source=SIS025;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=$DBSchema;Password=system')" />

<xsl:variable name="ConnectionString" select="concat('Data Source=SIS025;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=',DBSchema,';Password=system')" />

<xsl:variable name="ConnectionString" select="concat('Data Source=SIS025;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=',$DBSchema,';Password=system')" />
```

Neither of them worked. Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you mean:

```
<xsl:variable name="ConnectionString" select="concat('Data Source=SIS025;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=', $DBSchema, ';Password=system')" />
```

returns:

```
Data Source=SIS025;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=system
```

Comment: thanks yes, this concat is right, it's what I tried in my 3rd try. The problem was on an other place, where he can't read a string with concat. But thats not necessary for this question. I'd should have investigate that earlier.